# Graphical buttons in my Google sheets don't keep their position

Tags: google-apps-script, button, google-drawings

One of the annoying problems with Google sheet is the positioning the buttons. The buttons of the spreadsheet application may lose their original position ( due to user or unexpected behavior )

What to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to work around this problem is to programmatically reset the position of the buttons when the sheet is loaded.

```
const drawings = sheet.getDrawings();
const button = drawings.find(drawing => drawing.getOnAction() == "scriptName");
button.setPosition(row, col, offset_X, offset_Y);
```